# Pass value/data between pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

**Hi!**

I need to pass data from one step to another in a Jenkins pipeline. Something like this:

```
node { 
    // myPipelineStep is "my" own hello world pipeline step based on hello-world archetype, and I want it to return a variable that I have inside the plugin
    def return_value = myPipelineStep inputVariable: value

    // Then I want to do something else, a new step, where I use this value
    sh 'echo $return_value'

    //But the problem is I dont know how to return something from my pipeline step
}
```

But in the archetype empty-plugin the perform()-function where the action should take place **is void.. So it is not possible to return something here.**
[image]

**And the same goes for the hello-world acrhetype.**
[image]

Anyone with any leads?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify what is in the method ?? if so, create a global variable outside and assign the value inside the method.

Now the variable will have the value and you can use it in the other method
E.g.

```
   node{
def isVaild
void perform(.....) {
    //do stuff
    isValid =true;
}

@Override
void perform(.....) {
    //do stuff
    if(isValid){
    }
}
```

}

It should work :)

Comment: How should I be able to compile the java code if the variable is only declared in the pipeline and not declared within the plugin scope (the pipeline step)? When I run 'mvn package' it will just complain about my non-declared variable.

Comment: You might have a class which extends the Action class create a variable there and pass the value from the method to this variable and then in the pipeline get the value from your plugin...refer this https://jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/extend/

Comment: Im not sure if and how I can change that code inside Jenkins?